# Angular2 router navigate with multivalued query params

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Say, I've got a URL with multivalued parameter like:

```
http://my-domain.com?param1=aaa&param1=bbb
```

`activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams` will equal to: `{ param1: ['aaa', 'bbb'] }` - an object with both param1 values.

So far so good. Now, I want to modify one of the values. With "normal", single values parameters I do it with

```
router.navigate(['.'], { queryParams: { param: 'newValue' }}
```

However, when trying with an array of values:

```
router.navigate(['.'], { queryParams: { param1: ['aaa', 'ccc'] }}
```

it doesn't produce `?param1=aaa&param1=ccc`, but `?param1=aaa,ccc` instead.

The question is: how can I navigate to `?param1=aaa&param1=ccc` modifying just one of multiple values of a single param?
I hope there is a better option that building the whole URL myself and using `router.navigateByUrl`...?

Ultimately I can rewrite it to utilize comma-separated `param1=aaa,ccc` notation, but I'd like to avoid it.

ng version is 2.4.9

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried with `queryParamsHandling="merge"`? Maybe it works :P